# Impacts of using Salesforce object with a Lookup to the Account part of the PersonAccount as Entry Source

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, person-accounts

Here is my question regarding PersonAccount and Lookup to the Account Part of the PersonAccount.

On a Journey, when using an object as Entry Source, on which there is a Lookup field to the PersonAccount and especially to the ACCOUNT part of the PersonAccount, can you confirm that is it the AccountId that will be injected into the journey (and not the ContactId/PersonContactId of the PersonAccount ?).

As SFMC uses ContactId from the Contact as ContactKey once the connector is set up, does it mean using an Entry Source object with a Lookup to the Account part of the PersonAccount can create duplicates ? The same contact could exist in SFMC with a PersonAccountId as ContactKey and also a AccountId as ContactKey ?

Can you confirm that the best practice would be to use a Lookup field to the Contact part of the PersonAccount to use it more easily on Journey Builder / Salesforce Data Entry Source ?

Thanks

Comment: Best practice is to use LeadId for leads, ContactId for contacts and PersonContactId for person accounts. You get to choose in entry source config which Id will be used as Contact Key. Without further details, it’s hard to advise on best solution for your use case.

Comment: It seems that SFMC is "intelligent" : in the journey and the generated data extension linked to the journey, it automatically uses the PersonContactId as SubscriberKey when using an object with a Lookup to the PersonAccount field. So finally, that shouldn't be a problem and no duplicates should be created